# GPIO problem. RPIO terminal issue

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpio

If I run `gpio readall`, everything works fine and I see all GPIOs.

Terminal:

```
rpio -i 7
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# rpio -i 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rpio", line 345, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/rpio", line 147, in main
    import RPIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPIO/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    import RPIO._GPIO as _GPIO
SystemError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
```

Expected result: `1` or `0`

Any ideas?

Comment: The rpio command is unrelated to the gpio command.  One working or not working implies nothing about the other.

Comment: I think this looks an awful lot like [this issue](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/issues/78) described on the RPIO Github. The proposed solutions get kinda messy - lots of forks with lots of partial fixes. I *think* that the consensus on that page is that [this one](https://github.com/limuxy/RPIO) seems to work. You might have some luck cloning from there.